# How do I display a javascript variable in a webpage via HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new to coding so sorry if I'm doing it all wrong, and I know this is very basic.

I'm trying to get a string of text to appear in a webpage using a variable defined in JavaScript in HTML. I've done this so far but the content area is still empty, I don't know where I'm going wrong. I need the var biography to display in the content div when the page is first requested and whenever the button is clicked. Thanks in advance for any help.
HTML code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
    <title> Katie Jeynes </title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body onload="displayBiography();">

    <div id="leftBar"> 
    <button class="button" onclick="displayBiography();"> Biography 
    </button>
    </div>

    <div id="content" > 
    <script src="myJS.js"> </script>
    <script> displayBiography();</script>
    </div>


    </body>
    </html>
```

JS code:

```
    var content = document.getElementByID("content");

    var biography = "<p> Katie Jeynes is currently in her 3rd year of 
    study"+ 
    "undergraduate study etc </p>"
    ;


    function displayBiography() {
        "use strict";
        content.innerHTML = biography;
    }
```

Comment: It's `getElementById` not `getElementByID`. Also start learning the fundamentals of debugging with your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Get your scripts out of `<div id="content" ></div>`

Comment: Now is not too early to learn how to use the debugger and the other developer tools. In some browsers, this is accessed via Ctrl+Shift+I

Answer (score 0):

You can set the text by typing:

```
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = biography;
```

Comment: Is it your intention to nuke the javascript code at the same time? (It might be worth adding a note that mentions this will happen. While not likely a problem in this instance (too lazy to try the code) there are some cases obviously where this will be catastrophic.) No biggie, but that could be a nasty trap.

Answer (score 0):

If you run the code on a browser and use its console you'll see that you have a sintax error **"unterminated string literal"** (More info about it can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Unterminated_string_literal)) when defining biography.

You should use either this approach:

```
var biography = "<p> Katie Jeynes is currently in her 3rd year of study"+ 
"undergraduate study etc </p>";
```

or this one:

```
var biography = "<p> Katie Jeynes is currently in her 3rd year of study \ 
undergraduate study etc </p>";
```

If you'd like to add a breakline you can use the HTML tag `<br>` after the word study to show it to the user.

Also, as **j08691** mentioned, getElementById is the correct sintax, not getElementByID.

**RaphaMex** suggests you to remove the script call from content. You should this and I'd like to explain you why.

Because you are already calling displayBiography() (either by clicking or loading the page for the first time), content.innerHTML will already change the HTML node content and will put inside it the value of your biography.